# No output in Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I use autocomplete to achieve a Google like search where the search suggestions are in a dropdown while i type what i'm searching for.

**The Output of my code**

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <td width="155"  bgcolor="#999999">Client Name</td>
    <td width="218" bgcolor="#999999"><input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" class="forinput" /></td>
```

**script**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#clientname" ).autocomplete(
   {
     source:"getautocomplete.php",
     minLength:1
    })
       });
    </script>
```

**getautocomplete.php**

```
  ..databaseconnection
  $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

  $qstring = "SELECT clientname FROM client WHERE clientname LIKE '%".$term."%'";
  $result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
   {
    $row['clientname']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['clientname']));
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
   }
   echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

**What i want to achieve**
      [image]

I check my database connection and its correct. Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong? did i missed something?

Comment: You need to debug this and provide more specifics. Are you watching your browser's console (F12)? In the Network tab, can you see the AJAX requests to getautocomplete.php taking place? Is the `term` being sent?

Comment: See also [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Your query is vulnerable to injection, since `$term` is unescaped.

Comment: Also make sure on the PHP side that you have error reporting enabled and turned up.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the result you are sending back is valid according to what [jQueryUI is expecting](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Now you are building an array of arrays and you should only send the values back (assuming that the `label` and the `value` are the same, the name of the client):

```
// $row['clientname']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['clientname']));
$row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['clientname']));    //build an array
```

Also note the comments about the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and sql injection.